# Как правильно сформировать sources.list Debian?

Tags: debian

Это взаимозаменяющие строки? То есть по сути это одно и тоже?

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: у вас два никак не связанных вопроса в одном: один в заголовке, и совершенно другой — в теле вопроса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нужно изменить вопрос? могу изменить, только как нужно не знаю? Как то так: "Формирование зеркал в Debian ?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

да, по сути это одно и тоже ~ зеркала одного и того же репозитория. причём в обоих случаях происходит перенаправление, и в обоих случаях — на динамически выбранные серверы.

в идентичности репозиториев можно убедиться, например, по идентичному содержимому файлов `InRelease` — это подписанные списки файлов (с их контрольными суммами), содержащих списки пакетов:

```
$ wget -qO - http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease | md5sum
4d1e6adb30ed5af0858e576048664248  -
$ wget -qO - http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease | md5sum
4d1e6adb30ed5af0858e576048664248  -
```

---

а как правильно сформировать содержимое `sources.list`, написано, например, на [соответствующей wiki-странице](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/SourcesList).

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь я понял. Действительно это одно и тоже. Только вот остался один интересный момент. Вы сказали что происходит перенаправление, то есть получается если я укажу HTTPS меня всё равно перенаправят на HTTP ?

Comment: нет, под перенаправлением я имею ввиду именно перенаправление. если выполнить, например, `$ curl -I http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/`, то можно увидеть, что получен ответ 302 (это как раз и есть перенаправление) и адрес перенаправления: `Location: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian-security/`. p.s. а протокол https не имеет смысла использовать в sources.list: всё содержимое (официальных) репозиториев и так подписано. «защищать» излишним шифрованием просто нечего.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin *протокол https не имеет смысла использовать в sources.list: всё содержимое (официальных) репозиториев и так подписано. «защищать» излишним шифрованием просто нечего.* - также задавался подобным вопросом, с протоколами всё ясно, а вот почему именно так не знал, спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 0):

Первая строка вообще не должна работать. Т.ч. они разные.
Вторая - рабочая.

Собственно проход по ссылкам - намекает:

http://deb.debian.org/debian-security

http://security.debian.org/debian-security

[Ссылка на документацию Debian](https://www.debian.org/security/)

Comment: и та и другая ссылка рабочая 

http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/

http://security.debian.org/debian-security/

Comment: У меня результат по первой ссылке: `Not Found
The requested URL /debian-security was not found on this server.` Как и должно быть.

Comment: возможно Вы без http набераете?

Comment: С `http`. Прочитай: https://www.debian.org/security/

Comment: тогда откуда вот это появилось? 

http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/

Comment: Понятия не имею. Вот это первая строка `sources.list` в моей системе, с которой я пишу: `# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux testing _Wheezy_ - Official Snapshot amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20111023-21:40]/ wheezy main`. С тех пор твоя у меня не появлялась.

Comment: так это ж вроде комментарий

Comment: комментарий, он же вроде не на что не влияет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95874/discussion-between-anton-abrosimov-and-ivan).