# security-репозитории debian

Tags: debian, repository

В чем разница между

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ testing-security main contrib non-free

и

deb http://security.debian.org/ testing-security main contrib non-free

Добавка debian-security/ в адрес несет какую-то смысловую нагрузку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

то же самое или не то же самое. вот в чём вопрос.

повторяю то, что уже излагал в ответе на [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1000701/178576).

смотрим, совпадает ли содержимое файла `dists/testing-security/InRelease` по обоим адресам:

```
$ wget -qO - http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/testing-security/InRelease | md5sum
e2bca52e5bcd007f5cad3687b7360ba2  -
$ wget -qO - http://security.debian.org/dists/testing-security/InRelease | md5sum
e2bca52e5bcd007f5cad3687b7360ba2  -
```

хэш-суммы аналогичны. это копии одного и того же репозитория (вне зависимости от того, на каких машинах они физически располагаются).

Comment: Да, вопрос был про это. Спасибо!